# Passing a tar file from one pipeline to another

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, pipeline, jenkins-groovy

On my jenkins instance i have two pipelines.
Pipeline A and Pipeline B.

Pipeline A requires a lot of parameters to be built
Pipeline B triggers pipeline A using the "build job" declarative

I had no issue with passing string type parameters to pipeline A from pipeline B,
however when it came to passing a tar file parameter to pipeline A I tried everything I was able to found online and couldn't do it.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this issue?

I tried using the "build job" parameter: file, but no matter what I tried it didn't end up working. I also tried to use this: [$class: "FileParameterValue, name: "xxx", file: new FileParameterValue.FileItemImpl(new File("yyy"))]